# vTiger API - Add Product To Contact

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I'm currently evaluating vTiger CRM, and therefore I want some test data in.
The data is ingested via the API which works fine (Products, Organizations, Contacts).

Is there a way to use the API to assign a product to a contact (and vice versa) - as in the Web-View?
This is the only point I was not able to achieve with the API.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the API as it is out of the box. However, you can create your custom webservice functions and register them with vtlib. You would have the flexibility to do whatever you want. Of course that would take some time, specially if you are new to Vtiger.

Comment: Yeah Right, but you can write something that will act as per your requirement. See http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/server-apis.html and in this See "Query" section on this page, might help you little bit.

Comment: Please stop using signatures in your posts. Your posts already contain attribution in the form of your user card.